# Get data using same parameter with different values in sql

Tags: sql-server

I need to show multiple record tables using same parameter suppose some ID.
Data has been differ as per that parameter values which is different for all.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look here: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask maybe you will get more answers...

Comment: Your question isn't clear, can you please try to elaborate? Also add table's definition and some sample data of the outcome you need (DDL + DML).

Comment: I have attached image. As you see there will be LorrychallanNumber are unique. so i need to pass multiple LRno from UI which shows their respective data

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your requirement. But you can query sys.columns for column names to find the tables which have the same column

```
select
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as table_name, 
    name as column_name 
from sys.columns 
where 
    name like N'%id%'
```

For passsing a list of IDs into a stored procedure, most recent method is using Table Valued Parameters aka TVP

Following is an example for using TVP in SQL Server

First you need to create the type in database. Then you populate the variable of the table type with data. You have to do these in the front end. Then you pass this parameter to your stored procedure

I used databases view for sample, you can use your table and ID column instead

```
create type IDTableType as table
( 
    Id int
);
go

create procedure ReadData (
    @IdList IDTableType readonly
)
as   
    select *
    from sys.databases as d
    inner join @IdList as p
        on d.database_id = p.id
go

declare @IDs as IDTableType
insert into @IDs values (1),(5),(3)
exec ReadData @IDs
```

But maybe the most common usage is with string parameter which is concatenated form of IDs

This time you need a [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) to split input parameter into ID list. You can use the referred sample or use one of the custom split functions on the web. If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use [string_split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx), too

```
create procedure ReadData2 (
    @IdList varchar(max)
)
as   
    select *
    from sys.databases as d
    inner join dbo.split(@IdList,0,0) as s
    on d.database_id = s.val
go

declare @IDs as varchar(max) = '1,3,5,6'
exec ReadData2 @IDs
```

Comment: I have attached image. As you see there will be LorrychallanNumber are unique. so i need to pass multiple LRno from UI which shows their respective data

Comment: I modified the reply, maybe it can help

Comment: Thank You Guyz. This is working but i use function in place of TVP

Answer (score 0):

First thing i make fun in sql:

```
USE [ZAB_HCTMS]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[LCNos]    Script Date: 1/8/2019 1:09:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[oldTVP_ConsignmentNoteLineItems]    Script Date: 1/7/2019 1:00:53 PM ******/

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[LCNos]
(    
      @LCNo NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Comma CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      ID NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@LCNo, LEN(@LCNo) - 1, LEN(@LCNo)) <> @Comma
      BEGIN
            SET @LCNo = @LCNo + @Comma
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Comma, @LCNo) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Comma, @LCNo)

            INSERT INTO @Output(ID)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@LCNo, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @LCNo = SUBSTRING(@LCNo, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@LCNo))
      END

      RETURN
END
```

then sp for this:

```
-- EXEC GetLCsDetails '2188,2196,2201'

alter PROCEDURE GetLCsDetails
      @LCNos VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
      SELECT lr.*, lr.PayBalance 'TotalPayBalance', s.Name 'SuppName', 
      cb.AdvancePayment, s.[Address] 'Address', 
      s.PinCode, pod.SupplierBillNo

      FROM LorryChallans lr  

      left join ConsignmentBookings cb on lr.ConsignmentBookingID = 
      cb.ConsignmentBookingID
      left join Suppliers s on cb.VehicleSupplierID = s.SupplierID
      left join POD pod on lr.ConsignmentBookingID = pod.ConsignmentBookingID

      WHERE 

      lr.LorryChallanNumber       
      IN( SELECT CAST(ID AS INTEGER) FROM dbo.LCNos(@LCNos, ',') )

END
```

and finally passing string comma separated ids from jquery:

```
    function chk()
    {
        $('.Checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('data-lcno');
        }).get().join(',')
    }
```

data-lcno is data attribute to checkboxlist.